# Trying to update an object with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm new to react-redux and hooks. I'm building this simple CRUD employee management app, and I'm trying update an employee but I can't seem to make it work.  here is my code..

```
const EditEmployee = ({history, match}) => {
    const empById = match.params.id
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const emp = useSelector((state) => state.employee)
    const {loading, employee} = emp

    const [full_name, setFull_name] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [phone_number, setPhone_number] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getSingleEmployee(empById))
    }, [dispatch, empById])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (employee != null) {
            setFull_name(employee.full_name)
            setEmail(employee.email)
            setPhone_number(employee.phone_number)
            setAddress(employee.address)
        }
    }, [employee])


    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const updateEmp = {
            empById,
            full_name,
            email,
            phone_number,
            address
        }

        dispatch(updateEmployees(updateEmp))
        history.push('/home')
    }
```

Then it's giving me this Error

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "[object Object]"
```

Can someone please asssit.
And here is the backend..

Model:

```
 import Sequelize from "sequelize"
    import db from "../config/database.js";
    
    const Employee = db.define('employee', {
        full_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        phone_number: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        address: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
    })
    
    export default Employee
```

Controller:

```
const updateEmployee = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    const updates = req.body
    Employee.findOne({
        where: { id: id }
    })
        .then(employee => {
            if (employee) {
                return employee.update(updates)
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({message: 'Employee not found'})
                throw new Error('Employee not found')
            }
        })
        .then(updatedEmployee => {
            res.status(201).json(updatedEmployee);
        });
}
```

I think I did everything correctly, in postman everything seems to work

Comment: can you do a ```console.log(updateEmp)``` ? it looks like you're passing an object instead of an integer somewhere in your ```updateEmp``` object

Comment: Yes in the console.log() it does update, but not on the screen, and it's still giving me that `SequelizeDatabaseError`

Comment: we need to see the backend part where you do the update, because it looks like you're passing an object instead of a number somewhere, maybe the order of the arguments is not right..

Comment: Ok, I'll post it, it's posted above

Comment: The backend is Posted